# Store Image in HTML 5 Web SQL Database

Tags: image, html, offline

How can store offline Image in HTML 5 Web SQL Database?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010290/in-html5-can-you-save-an-image-to-cache-programmatically  
Looks like a similar question

Comment: Why not just use a [cache manifest](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you'll have to store it as `data:` URL with base64 encoding which increases file size by 33%.

However, first try using, in that order:

1. HTTP cache. Set long expiry headers, `Cache-control: public`. If you don't need long-term off-line capability, it will "just work".
2. HTML5 offline "web application" feature (add image to manifest file). This way image will be stored by the browser without extra overhead.
3. `localStorage`. WebSQL spec is deprecated and its replacement, IndexedDB, isn't widely supported yet. Local Storage is also faster than WebSQL.