# How to remove the image cache

Tags: html, objective-c, cordova, sencha-touch

If `image` is exist in our `server` then I will display that `image` otherwise I will display default `image`. I know we have to add some `random number` to the end of the `image url` then the url will load again. But my requirement is I want to change the `src` of the `image` when click the `button`. New `image` will take 2-3 sec time to load so at that time previous `image` displayed. I don't want to display previous `image` at the time of new `image` loading. How can i resolve this issue.
 
Anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can show loading text in the center of div where you want to show image..when image is loaded then you can remove the text..

Comment: @Rajesh previously i have done that one but client don't want to display loading text/symbol

Comment: ok..in that case you can show a loading throbber..which should be of very less size..so that it will load first and then other image which wanted to show..other option is you can try storing image in browser storage but this solution wont make ur app browser compatible..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010290/in-html5-can-you-save-an-image-to-cache-programmatically